# Quickest way to remove mirror opposites from a list

Tags: python, logic, python-itertools

Say I have a list of tuples `[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (3, 2, 1, 0)]`, I would like to remove all instances where a tuple is reversed e.g. removing `(3, 2, 1, 0)` from the above list.

My current (rudimentary) method is:

```
L = list(itertools.permutations(np.arange(x), 4))

for ll in L:
    if ll[::-1] in L:
        L.remove(ll[::-1])
```

Where time taken increases exponentially with increasing x. So if x is large this takes ages! How can I speed this up?

Comment: removing stuff from a list as you loop through it is a bad idea.

Comment: do you remove `(3, 2, 1, 0)` and not `(0, 1, 2, 3)` simply because the latter comes first?

Comment: It doesn't matter which is removed

Comment: can it be that you have multiple duplicates in the big `list`?

Comment: But in your example code you are creating a list with *x permute 4* elements. This is equal to x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3). This is an order 4 polynomial which inherently grows very fast -- O(x^4). If x = 100 for instance, L contains almost 100 million elements. Of course your code will be slow using this example.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis no not using the `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Thanks @Denziloe yes this is my problem and why I need a better solution - sorry for the poor math!

Comment: Then what you are trying to do is unclear. Your code isn't slow because of your algorithm, your code is slow because it has to create the huge example list you chose. But you state the problem as if the list could be anything?

Comment: @kungphil I thought you were building just an example list with that. Ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `set` comes to mind:

```
L = set()
for ll in itertools.permutations(np.arange(x), 4):
    if ll[::-1] not in L:
        L.add(ll)
```

or even, for slightly better performance:

```
L = set()
for ll in itertools.permutations(np.arange(x), 4):
    if ll not in L:
        L.add(ll[::-1])
```

Comment: but even if the inverse of `ll` exists in the `list` \ `set`, you do want one of them in the result.. That's the tricky bit.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis so I **do** add one, if the other one has **not** been added yet.

Comment: Also, please note how this approach reduces memory use by **not** creating a temporary list.

Answer (score 1):

The need to keep the first looks like it forces you to iterate with a contitional.

```
a = [(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (3, 2, 1, 0)]
s = set(); a1 = []
for t in a:
    if t not in s:
        a1.append(t)
        s.add(t[::-1])
```

**Edit:** The accepted answer addresses the example code (i.e. the itertools permutations sample).  This answers the generalized question for any list (or iterable).

Comment: No need for a1. If you really need a list, `list(s)` will produce it.

Comment: @Błotosmętek understood, but it would not preserve order. It would not really resemble the original with the reverse-dupes removed.

Comment: I don't see the requirement of preserving order in OP's description of the problem…